# Download a folder from Github with docker ADD

Tags: linux, git, docker

Need to download a folder from Github.
Use this site to get a link: https://downgit.github.io/#/home
Use the link in Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
ADD https://downgit.github.io/#/home?url=https://github.com/apache/flink-web/tree/asf-site/visualizer \
/usr/share/nginx/html
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add bash && apk add unzip
```

But I receive an **unnamedfile**.
It isn't a zip format. If I try to unzip - see a message incorrect format or archive.

How I can fix this issue and download a zip file?
Is there exist a way to download a specific folder from Github in tar.gz?

Comment: Found solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use svn to download subdirectory from github. Also you can list folders that you want to download by using "svn ls [https://github.com/apache/flink-web/trunk"](https://github.com/apache/flink-web/trunk%22). "visualizer" folder is under trunk subdirectory.

```
FROM nginx:alpine

USER root

RUN apk update &&  apk add subversion

RUN svn export https://github.com/apache/flink-web/trunk/visualizer
```

Comment: This method no longer works as of Jan 2024. Just learned  the hard way when a rarely built image that used this method to obtain some redistributables failed to build. The repo is still up and public and the tag wasn't deleted, but the `svn export` method simply stopped working. It says "Unable to connect to a repository at URL '<the URL>'".